# How to uncover piecewise content that comes after a list in beamer?

Tags: beamer, itemize, overlays

When I want to uncover list items in beamer, some of the content which comes after the list are already there from the start. For example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item One
\item Two
\end{itemize}

This is what is showing up with item One, when it should show up after item Two.

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas on how to make anything after the list show up after the entire list has been made visible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
[...]
\end{itemize}

\onslide<+->{%
     This is what is showing up with item One, when it should show up after item Two.}
[...]
```

Comment: This worked but for some reason the slide with the last sentence (uncovered) is duplicated. How can remove one of these slides?

Comment: see my edited answer

Comment: This answer should be extended, as it's too short, in my point of view